# MVC 5 - Unable to find views that are clearly in the solution

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

Good day.  I was wondering if anyone has run into an issue that I am experiencing with MVC 5.  We have an MVC 5 application that end users hit pretty regularly on a daily basis.  The problem that we are seeing is that during heavy load times the application can no longer locate the default Index view.  We see the standard error message “The view ‘Index’ or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations…”. Reviewing our logs, we do see that the code within the ActionResult does fire but the application fails on “return View()”.  An app reset corrects the issue at first but will eventually crash again with the same error message.  The view does exist and the application works correctly until the crash occurs.

Comment: Might it be that your server is unable to serve up the file and that is what is causing the issue? I would suggest looking there first for a solution. I am sure your code & MVC configuration is fine.

Comment: did you try to return view with viewname?